# Pandas: finding mean in the dataframe based on condition included in another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes, just like below.

Dataframe1:

| country | type | start_week | end_week |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 12 | 13 |
| 2 | b | 13 | 14 |

Dataframe2:

| country | type | week | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 12 | 1000 |
| 1 | a | 13 | 900 |
| 1 | a | 14 | 800 |
| 2 | b | 12 | 1000 |
| 2 | b | 13 | 900 |
| 2 | b | 14 | 800 |

I want to add to the first dataframe column with the mean value from the second dataframe for key (country+type) and between start_week and end_week.

I want desired output to look like the below:

| country | type | start_week | end_week | avg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 12 | 13 | 950 |
| 2 | b | 13 | 14 | 850 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is one way :

```
combined = df1.merge(df2 , on =['country','type'])
combined = combined.loc[(combined.start_week <= combined.week) & (combined.week <= combined.end_week)]
output = combined.groupby(['country','type','start_week','end_week'])['value'].mean().reset_index()
```

output:

```
>>
   country type  start_week  end_week  value
0        1    a          12        13  950.0
1        2    b          13        14  850.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pd.melt and comparison of numpy arrays.

```
# melt df1
melted_df1 = df1.melt(id_vars=['country','type'],value_name='week')[['country','type','week']]

# for loop to compare two dataframe arrays
result = []
for i in df2.values:
    for j in melted_df1.values:
        if (j == i[:3]).all():
            result.append(i)
            break

# Computing mean of the result dataframe
result_df = pd.DataFrame(result,columns=df2.columns).groupby('type').mean().reset_index()['value']

# Assigning result_df to df1
df1['avg'] = result_df

   country type  start_week  end_week    avg
0        1    a          12        13  950.0
1        2    b          13        14  850.0
```